# CSS error: "Don't use IDs in selectors" how can i fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have these code for having an animated background for my Html page (i found this code on the internet).
every time that I save the CSS file I get this error: "Don't use IDs in selectors.". 
how can I fix this?

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<div id="smoke">
  <span class="s0"></span>
  <span class="s1"></span>
  <span class="s2"></span>
  <span class="s3"></span>
  <span class="s4"></span>
  <span class="s5"></span>
  <span class="s6"></span>
  <span class="s7"></span>
  <span class="s8"></span>
  <span class="s9"></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {background: #18d0f0}

/* Smoke container */

#smoke {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 1px; height: 160px;
    left: 50%; bottom: 30px;
}

/* No animations? Display a static smoke image */

.disableAnimations #smoke,
.no-cssanimations #smoke {
    width: 86px;
    margin-left: -25px;
    bottom: 146px;
    background: url('../img/smokeNoAni.png') no-repeat center bottom;
}

/* smoke balls */

.cssanimations #smoke span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -35px; left: 50%; margin-left:-20px;
    height: 0px; width: 0px;
    border: 35px solid #4b4b4b;
    border-radius: 35px;
    left: -14px; opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.2);
}
```

Comment: Looks like a lint error/warning. Please, provide more details, where do you get this message?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution is to change that id smoke to class smoke...

so html - `<div class="smoke">`
and css instead `#smoke` will be `.smoke`

Problem solver... But if you provide us with name of IDE or where are you getting that error we can help with the problem.

Comment: @NetanelBenIsahar from what i know you can use IDs as selectors... it is a warning i think only... problem with IDs as selectors is that you can have only one ID on one site so its not reusable... if you wanted to have more smoke elements on one page you would have invalid HTML code...

Comment: @NetanelBenIsahar if i helped, please accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

you should replace id by a class, 
id is for anchor for example, it's better to use class for style

```
<div class="smoke"></div>
```

and replace in your css file:

```
#smoke {
}
```

by

```
.smoke {
}
```